# Can't receive Accelerometer data UM7

Tags: c, sensors

I work with an UM7

> The UM7 orientation sensor from Redshift Labs is an Attitude and Heading Reference System (AHRS) that contains a three-axis accelerometer, rate gyro, and magnetometer.

I can get the data form the gyro but not form the accel. I do the same thing for both (except for the addresses I read).
To retrieve the data I use the sample code given in the [datasheet](https://www.pololu.com/file/0J1556/UM7%20Datasheet_v1-8_30.07.2018.pdf) (page 35).

I calibrate the UM7 before trying to receive data by sending the command 0xAD and 0xB1 ([datasheet](https://www.pololu.com/file/0J1556/UM7%20Datasheet_v1-8_30.07.2018.pdf) page 78).

Thank you for your help

Comment: Show your code, how you read gyro and attempt to read accel. What does mean "can't get data"? Is data wrong?

Comment: To get info about the um7 you need to send a command to the address that holds it. the um7 then respond with a bus with that address and the data but i never get that response when i ask for the addresses holding the accel info. And for the code i use the code given in the datasheet

Comment: The datasheet provides only examples how to compose request and parse response but not how to send/recieve them. Send/recieve functionality depends on your master device. Do you use SPI or UART? To what platform UM7 is connected to? Provide your code for communication functions, how do you initialize device etc.